# Can graduated values be added as an attribute in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

With QGIS Layer Properties > Graduated, we can get values sorted by some criteria as Natural Breaks (Jenks). Is there a way to add this as attribute values of the data? For example, if a specific field is classified into 4 classes, I would like to add this to a field called class with values of 1, 2, 3, and 4.

Comment: Interesting question. At least not with expressions. But **maybe** thats doable with some custom python.

Comment: You want the class value or class legend? Or just the "numbering"?

Answer (score 7):

You can try this:

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer() #Click/highlight layer in layer tree
valueField = 'area' #Change to match your fieldname
fieldToUpdate = 'Classfield' #Same
fieldToUpdateWithLegend = 'ClassLeg' #Same. If you also want the Legend values/text. If not comment this line with # and line down below

r = lyr.renderer()
l = []

for ra in r.ranges():
    l.append([ra.lowerValue(), ra.upperValue()])
l[0][0]-=1
l[-1][1]+=1
# l is: [[-0.3, 152.2], [152.2, 485.9], [485.9, 1330.1], [1330.1, 2311.6], [2311.6, 67652.2]]

legendlist = [i.label() for i in r.legendSymbolItems()]

with edit(lyr):
    for f in lyr.getFeatures():
        for e, cl in enumerate(l,1):
            #e, cl is for example: 0 [-0.3, 152.2]
            if cl[0] <= f[valueField] < cl[1]:
                f[fieldToUpdate] = e
                f[fieldToUpdateWithLegend] = legendlist[e-1] #Comment out this aswell
                lyr.updateFeature(f)
```

[image]
(Am I the only one that sometimes get a vertical red line in python editor?)

Comment: Thats genius! I understand how Id get the class values, but can you explain how I'd go about the legend?

Comment: @BERA, I think it is a bit tricky with borders in `cl[0] <= f[valueField] <= cl[1]`, because what if there is a value, that lies exactly on the edge (152.2), so into which group will it go, upper `[152.2, 485.9]` or lower `[0.7, 152.2]`, basically which class will it be?

Comment: @Taras yes. Could be solved using `eval`. And probably in some other way, I'll have to think about it

Comment: @MrXsquared using the label method of legendSymbolItems object `[i.label() for i in r.legendSymbolItems()]` -> `['1 - 152', '152 - 486', '486 - 1330', '1330 - 2312', '2312 - 67651']`. I updated the code

Answer (score 2):

In a manual approach you can use the Field Calculator with a `Case` expression:

[image]

The expression between the `WHEN` and `THEN` you do not need to write in hand, if you convert your graduated style to a rule style, it will write the expression for you to copy an paste. Doable with 4 classes but a pain with 50 classes.

Comment: Your solutions works perfectly if you manually set the values for the classes, taking their values one by one from the styling panel. As you say, a pain with a huge number of classes (even though it's questionable if 50 classes make sense: how many different classes can you really distinguish with your eyes?). Still it would be interesting if there is an automatic solution to this, without manually copying from the rule based style.